# Problem with slow hql query in grails app

Tags: sql, hibernate, grails, hql

I have this hql query but it takes so long (10 minutes) to be executed since its basically sweep the whole table. I was wondering if there is other way to write this to run faster.

What I am doing in this query is to list all the position for a particular date and if for that date there is no position I want to pick the most recent one.

```
    def flList = FlPosition.findAll(" from FlPosition f \ 
      where f.asOfDate = ( \   
         select max(f2.asOfDate) \ 
         from FlPosition f2  \
         where f2.cusip = f.cusip and \
               f2.shareholderAccount = f.shareholderAccount and  \
               f2.asOfDate <= ?)", [date] \
        ) \
   "
```

Comment: Do you have an index defined for FlPosition.asOfDate?

Comment: Yes all the fields have index. cusip, shareholderaccount and date

Comment: @Alidad, that is a common mistake made in indexing.  If you look at the explain plan in your database for the query, you'll see that only 1 index can be chosen per table.  If you need multiple fields indexed in a single query, then create a composite index.

Comment: @Alidad, also, what db are you running.  This is certainly geared more toward the db optimization that grails.  I'd try to first get this right in pure sql before translating into hql.

Comment: @Scott, I am using Oracle 11G db and I have composite indexes, the one that I have is asOfDate, shareholderaccount, cusip, and another field.

Comment: Are fields in index in that exact order? How many records are there per date? per `cusip` + `shareholderAccount`? Shouldn't you also limit exernal `FlPosition` query with `cusip` and `shareholderAccount`, or is it intended - all `FlPosition`s for all shareholders for particular shareholder's date?